# R: Assign values of a loop to a new matrix

Tags: r

I am currently trying to assign all the rows in which the if statement holds into a new matrix. I am doing the following:

```
obj=data.frame() 

tol = 1                        #tolerance level

for (i in 1:10) { 

if(abs(X$pickup[i] - 40.6397) < tol && abs(X$drop[i] - -73.7789) < tol){

obj[i, ] <- X[i]

}

}
```

This results into something nonsense (obj[10,0] when X[,24]), any ideas what the problem is?. Thanks!

Comment: please show what you get, and what you want to get as output

Comment: Also, `&` and `&&` are not the same

Comment: What I get is:   obj[10,0] ... X has 24 columns

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to extract the rows of `X` where `X$pickup` is within some tolerance level of 40.6397 and `X$drop` is within some tolerance level of -73.7789. You can do this in one line with:

```
obj <- X[abs(X$pickup - 40.6397) < tol & abs(X$drop - -73.7789) < tol,]
```

Note that I removed the loop and replaced `&&` with `&`.